# Get data send by one activity to all activities

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent

I have activity A and it calls activity B using Intent and putting some data in intent .Now I want to access data send by A in activity C.Can I do this?If Yes then how?

Comment: How you are calling the C activity?  From A or from B?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how these activities live and create from?

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar It is seperate activity I am not calling it from A or B.I just need data send by to B for updation of view purpose

Comment: Then you have to save some where like prefs or application storage.

Comment: you can use shared preferences for same..

Comment: @PankajKumar in my app A calls B number of times so do I need to save every time?

Comment: yes if you are using prefrences, there is no problem to save everytime

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple Use this piece of code

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

Or you can use `SharedPreference` in `ActivityA` then retrieve in `ActivityC` 
Or You can use `POJO` (i.e `getter` & `setter`) to Set in in `ActivityA` then Get in `ActivityC`

**e.g**

```
    public class Example{

     private String name;
     private int age;

     public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
     }

     public String getName(){
        return this.name;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in ActivityA like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassB.class);
intent.putExtra("yourKey", yourValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

get your values from ActivityB using this

```
Intent intentA = getIntent();
String yourString = intentA.getStringExtra("yourKey");
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Create the base activity for all the activities and pass the date in that activity through a method in bundle. Now you can get this data at any activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)** to save values and can access it from Any ACtivity

[More on Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)